# Retrieve size integer values SQL Server table with INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS view

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

Given this table:

[image]

and this query:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,
  NUMERIC_PRECISION, IS_NULLABLE
FROM
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE
  TABLE_NAME='PARAMETERS'
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION
```

I get this result:

[image]

How can I retrieve the size of the integer columns? For `PAR_ID` (Lenght = 2) I get a `NUMERIC_PRECISION` of 5.

Definition of `NUMERIC_PRECISION` is "Precision of approximate numeric data, exact numeric data, integer data, or monetary data. Otherwise, NULL is returned". But why a value of 5 for smallint(2) and for example a value of 53 for float(8)? What does this values mean?

UPDATE:

Thanks to @Ed_Harper: there is difference between Length and Precision. Length is the number of bytes that are used to store the number. Precision is the number of digits in a number. See: http://goo.gl/EOTyC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The storage sizes of the members of the int family are fixed, as documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx) (link is for SQL 2012 but this hasn't changed since SQL 2000):

```
tinyint  = 1 byte
smallint = 2 bytes
int      = 4 bytes
bigint   = 8 bytes
```

The easiest way to get this information into a query will be to hard code it in a case statement.

`NUMERIC_PRECISION` - determines the total number of decimal digits which can be stored in a numeric data type. This value is 5 for `smallint`, 10 for `int` etc. because that's the longest sequence of digits each datatype can store.

**EDIT**

Sample query showing use of case statement. Note that the list of datatypes is incomplete.

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,
  NUMERIC_PRECISION, IS_NULLABLE,DATA_TYPE,
  CASE DATA_TYPE WHEN  'tinyint'  THEN 1
                 WHEN  'smallint' THEN 2
                 WHEN  'int'      THEN 4
                 WHEN  'bigint'   THEN 8
                 WHEN  'datetime' THEN 8
                 WHEN  'nvarchar' THEN CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH * 2
                 WHEN  'nchar'    THEN CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH * 2
                 WHEN  'varchar'  THEN CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
                 WHEN  'char'     THEN CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
                 ELSE  NULL
  END AS column_size_bytes
FROM
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
  order by data_type
```

Comment: Thanks, I now see there is a difference between Length and Precision. I'll update my question

Comment: Although I still don't know how to query the length of my numeric table columns

Comment: @waanders - added a sample case statement

Comment: Thanks. However, this is a lot of code, you would expect the Length-value found somewhere in a `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` view

Comment: @waanders - `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is an ANSI standard designed to be platform agnostic. Different RDBMS systems implement storage in different ways and this may be the reason the schema doesn't include this information.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL 2000, try this (untested):

```
SELECT c.name AS ColumnName, TYPE_NAME(c.xusertype) AS DataType, 
    c.length, c.PREC, c.scale
FROM sysobjects t
    JOIN syscolumns c ON t.id = c.id
WHERE t.name = 'PARAMETERS'
```

From SQL 2005+ try:

Try sys.columns instead...

```
SELECT c.name AS ColumnName, ty.name AS DataType, c.max_length, 
    c.precision, c.scale
FROM sys.tables t
    JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
    JOIN sys.types ty ON c.system_type_id = ty.system_type_id
WHERE t.name = 'PARAMETERS'
```

Comment: But I want to use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS. And was wondering what the size/length values for the integer columns mean

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT c.TABLE_NAME, c.COLUMN_NAME, c.DATA_TYPE, c.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,
  c.NUMERIC_PRECISION, c.IS_NULLABLE,sc.max_length
FROM
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c inner join sys.columns sc
  on c.TABLE_NAME=object_name(sc.object_id)
WHERE
  c.TABLE_NAME='PARAMETERS'
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION
```

SQL server 2000

```
  SELECT distinct c.TABLE_NAME, c.COLUMN_NAME, c.DATA_TYPE, c.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,
  c.NUMERIC_PRECISION, c.IS_NULLABLE,sc.length
FROM
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c inner join syscolumns sc

  on c.TABLE_NAME=object_name(sc.id)
WHERE
  c.TABLE_NAME='PARAMETERS'
```

Comment: I get duplicate rows: 64 rows where I have just 8 columns

Comment: just try this query running and see how many results you get--"SELECT *
FROM syscolumns
where id=object_id('PARAMETERS')"

Comment: Ideally it shud return only 8.I have updated query with distinct pls try